# pyupdater can't update installed program on MacOs - destination path already exists

Tags: python, macos, installation, pyinstaller, pyupdater

I'm trying to update using [PyUpdater](http://www.pyupdater.org) a Python app which I have build using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) and installed on a Mac using [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html).

The update process fails when pyupdater tries to execute the `extract_restart` and then `_overwrite` method from `pyupdater/client/updates.py`  (to be exact the `move` function from `shutil.py` called by the `_overwrite` fails with the command: 
**`destination path already exists`**).

The updating process works fine as long as the app is not installed. However - I need it to be installed which then fails. I assume this is due to access to the access right restrictions in the Programs folder...

Can anybody hint me how to overcome this issue? I'm getting a bit hopeless here ...:/

Comment: You ever work this one out? I am having my own issues with Pyupdater updating

Comment: @TysonDogerzonda - No I was not able to get resolve this. Because of that we eventually moved away from PyUpdater and used Electron.io which did the trick!! Maybe it will prove useful also for you? :)

Comment: Hahaha, darn.  Electron is great.  Though you could argue, Electron is just a web app with a desktop skin xD.  The bulk of the work is done on the server